# Woocommerce Stripe gateway payment method custom style

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I try to customize the style for the stripe gateway payment method (credit card), I used this guideline https://woocommerce.com/document/stripe-styling-fields/
but still have some issues, with my code:
CSS

```
.woocommerce form .form-row input.input-text {   
  padding: 17px 0 16px 24px; 
}
```

PHP

```
add_filter("wc_stripe_elements_styling", "snippetpress_style_stripe_1");
function snippetpress_style_stripe_1($styles)
{
  $styles = array(
    "base" => array(
      "fontFamily" => "galanogrotesque,sans-serif",
      "::placeholder" => array(
          "color" => "#979AA3",
          "fontSize" => "18px",
          "fontStyle" => "normal",
          "fontWeight" => "400",
          "lineHeight" => "normal",
          "letterSpacing" => "-0.2px",
          "textDecoration"  => "none",
          "fontVariant" => "normal",
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $styles;
}
```

I still need some changes:

- make CVV and Exp date in full width (now is displayed like 2 columns)
- the placeholder text is a few pixels higher

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: It looks like those fields are not actually part of your site there, they appear to be inside of an iframe, loaded from Stripe's domain - which means, you can not style them with _your_ CSS at all, that doesn't reach inside iframes, and since it is from a different domain, you can not "inject" it via JavaScript either. You are limited to whatever formatting options stripe offers via parameters or similar then.

Comment: @CBroe correct - is iframe